# Adding 2 Variable to file in expect script

Tags: bash, shell-script, expect

I am using a expect script & i am unable to set 2 variable to the output file, I just want to name the file as required.

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set file [lindex $argv 0];
set date [exec date "+%d-%B-%Y"]
spawn sh -c "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hostname < ./script.sh > /root/scp_output_$file_$date.txt"
```

Required output

```
/root/scp_output_A_21-September-2017.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The error I see for some test code is

```
can't read "file_": no such variable
    while executing
```

which indicates that TCL is looking for a `file_` variable that does not exist. This can be remedied by noting where the variable beings and end; TCL uses the same syntax as Perl for this, `{}` around the variable name.

```
spawn sh -c "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hostname < ./script.sh > /root/scp_output_${file}_${date}.txt"
```